# Angularjs unique options list ng-repeat or ng-options?

Tags: angularjs, json, google-sheets

I am working on building my first App with Angularjs - I have been editing the code below on codepen to try and accomplish a search / filter of items from a json file from a googlesheet.

So far it is working however I have run into 2 issues that I would like some advice on.

1. Filtering unique options in the dropdown filters. I have tried to integrate a few different version of things I have found online, but I am running into a deadend.
2. I also want to paginate the results.

I would really appreciate a bit of help with the first element with the unique filer or ng-options - and maybe a bit of a steer on how a second controller could be applied to the code to enable pagination.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
//
app.controller('SuperCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  
  
  $http.get("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1JrDA9x8F8BglGhb30wbbZ4FfmHJsb6CbaGKhb19hedc/1/public/values?alt=json")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.tools = response.feed.entry;
                                 
 

  });
  
  
});
 
//
```

```css
.row {
  width: 1200px;
}

.pimg {
  width:100%;
}

.product {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 32%!important;
  margin: 8px;
}
.form-inline {
  width: 100%;
  background: #1c1c1c;
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
}

.form-inline input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Tools and Tips for 1:1</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 11.1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.0.3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
    .row {
        margin:auto;
    }
    </style>
 
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SuperCtrl">
 
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1>On the computer</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" ">
           <!-- <form class="form-inline">
            <input ng-model='search.content.$t' type="text" placeholder="Search our Database of products" autofocus>-->
        </div>
                  <div class=" ">
              <select  ng-model='search.gsx$brand.$t' name="cars">
                <option value="" selected>Select A Brand</option>
                <option value="all" selected>Any Brand</option>
                <option ng-repeat="entry in tools"  value="{{ entry.gsx$brand.$t }}" >{{ entry.gsx$brand.$t }}</option>

              </select>
              
              <select ng-model='search.gsx$rrp.$t' name="cars">
                <option value="" selected>Choose A Price</option>
                <option value="" selected>Any Price</option>
                <option ng-repeat="entry in tools"  value="{{ entry.gsx$rrp.$t }}" >{{ entry.gsx$rrp.$t }}</option>
              </select>
              
                
        </div>

     
    </div>
 <!--ng-show="search.gsx$brand.$t"-->
    <div class="row">
      <div  ng-repeat="entry in tools | filter: search | orderBy:'gsx$focus.$t'" class="col-md-3 product">
        <img class="pimg" ng-src="{{ entry.gsx$img.$t}}"></img>
         <h4><a href="{{ entry.gsx$url.$t }}">{{ entry.gsx$title.$t }} </a></h4>
         <div class="description">{{ entry.gsx$rrp.$t}}</div>
         {{ entry.gsx$saleprice.$t }} 
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>   
    
</body>
</html>
```

http://codepen.io/tmkcreative/pen/XMypEL

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What are your problems? What do you currently have? And what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi Hoa, yes they are ambitious but I like to challenge myself when learning. The codepen above is my starting point. I am able to create multiple dropdowns as filters, the first step would be to filter the unique values in the given field they are searching - but I am struggling to get the UNIQUE property to work. I have been applying it to the ng-repeat of the following '<option ng-repeat="entry in tools | unique:'gsx$rrp.$t'"  value="{{ entry.gsx$rrp.$t }}" >{{ entry.gsx$rrp.$t }}</option>' but this approach does not seem to work. Do I need to add some JS to get the unique values?

Comment: Ideally I would be able to apply the same filter to multiple option dropdowns.

Comment: sorry misread the ambiguous with ambitious :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the `unique` filter is not an Angular built-in filter. The filter is provided by multiple third-party libraries such as [angular-filer](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter).

This is [a modified version of your CodePen](http://codepen.io/buithehoa/pen/dvLzbL?editors=1000) in which `angular-filter` is used. The changes are as follows:

In the HTML file, add

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.15/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
```

In the JS file, inject `angular-filter`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'angular.filter' ]);
```

Then you can filter brands as follows

```
<option
  ng-repeat="entry in tools | unique:'gsx$brand.$t'"
  value="{{ entry.gsx$brand.$t }}" >
  {{ entry.gsx$brand.$t }}
</option>
```

Comment: Thank you very - much Hoa - I think the fact it was not a built-in filter was throwing me off! This is much appreciate top class response!!!